# Export pie chart to powerpoint using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, powerpoint, pie-chart

i am trying to Export a pie chart to powerpoint slide uisng c# but not found any similar article which can help me...

please provide me some example or provide some useful link which can help me in achieving this functionality easily...

thanks,
Aman

Answer (score 1):

we are using [hipdf](http://www.hiqpdf.com/downloads.aspx) library but this is paid and we are converting html to image first and then showing this image on ppt slide. You can also do it by using inkscape exe file

Answer (score 0):

In button_click event write following code.

```
GridView1.AllowPaging = false; //write this code only if paging is enabled.
GridView1.DataBind(); //write this code only if paging is enabled.

Response.Clear();

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.ppt");//for text file write FileName.txt

Response.Charset = "";

// If you want the option to open the Excel file without saving than comment out the line below
// Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ppt";\\for text file write vnd.txt

System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

Response.End();

GridView1.AllowPaging = true; //write this code only if paging is enabled.

GridView1.DataBind();//write this code only if paging is enabled.
```

You will have to override function of VerifyRenderingInServerForm like this

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    //Keep it empty
}
```

And to avoid exception you have to set property of

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Comment: please add some details, so that we can understand your code example

Comment: @oberfreak If you could have read carefully, you'd see the details inside of the code it's self.